# Как работать с response, полученным в Callback не UI-потока Okhttp

Tags: java, android, http

Есть такая функция System.out.println работает, а Log вызывает ошибку, понятно что Callback получает response не в пользовательском потоке, потому и не работает, а как его засунуть в пользовательский, чтоб можно было дальше работать с response?

```
public void getResponseAsynchronously(String url, String json) throws Exception {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("response " +response.body().string());
                    //Log.v(TAG, "response " + response.body().string()); //Ошибка

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: Приведите логи ошибки. Из logCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант использовать AsyncTask.

```
public void getResponseAsynchronously(String url, String json) throws Exception {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();


  final Call call = client.newCall(request);
  new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response>() {
    @Override public Response doInBackground(Void... args) {
      try {
        return call.execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    @Override public void onPostExecute(Response response) {
      if (response != null) {
        // Этот метод выполняется на UI потоке.
      }
    }
  }.execute();
}
```

Есть вариант через Handler

```
private static final android.os.Handler sMainHandler = 
    new android.os.Handler(android.os.Looper.getMainLooper());

public void getResponseAsynchronously(String url, String json) throws Exception {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();

  client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("response " +response.body().string());
      //Log.v(TAG, "response " + response.body().string()); //Ошибка
      sMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          // Этот метод будет выполняться на UI потоке
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
    }
  });
}
```

Если вы работаете в рамках Activity то вместо `Handler#post(Runnable)` можно воспользоваться методом [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: А если я сам метод getResponseAsynchronously запускаю в AsyncTask, это будет ошибкой? Хотя у меня все работает.

Comment: @Gennady, okhttp разрабатывался с учетом возможности вызовов из разных потоков, так что метод описанный выше будет работать как при вызове из заглавного так и из других потоков.